# Datatask with semaphore not working as intended

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to make a URL request but waiting for it to be done prior to letting another URL request go through by using semaphore. Seems like the following code waits for semaphore timeout (10 seconds) and only then the datatask response happens.

In other words, execution does not go to semaphore.signal() before timeout happens. If I set the timeout to "distantFuture", the execution hangs.

```
static func makeHTTPPostRequestJsonWait(path: String, body: [String: AnyObject], onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: path)!)
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    // Set the method to POST
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let json = JSON(body)
    let jsonString = json.rawString()

    // Set the POST body for the request
    let jsonBody = jsonString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpBody = jsonBody
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        semaphore.signal()
        if let jsonData = data {
            let json:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)
            onCompletion(json, nil)
        } else {
            onCompletion(nil, error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.now() + 10)
}
```

Comment: Do not wait! Learn to understand the asynchronous pattern and use a completion handler.

Comment: Yeah I know how that works but I have a service that doesn't allow too many concurrent requests so I have to do some traffic control. I'd like to learn why this isn't working anyway.